# Two Dropdowns in Jetpack Compose to be equal width

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add to dropdown components side by side, but the second one doesn't fill the available space, I'm trying to have the fields as two equal width fields and/or take up the available space.

[image]

The code for the dropdown:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Dropdown() {
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    var coffeeDrinks = arrayOf( "One", "Two", "Three" )

    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false )
    }
    var selectedText by remember {
        mutableStateOf(  coffeeDrinks[0] )
    }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth( 0.5f )
            .padding(all = 8.dp),
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = selectedText,
            onValueChange = {},
            readOnly = true,
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .menuAnchor()
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )

        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
        ) {
            coffeeDrinks.forEach { item ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = item) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedText = item
                        expanded = false
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then place this in the UI like so:

```
@Composable
fun ThisLayoutUI() {

    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    var email = "abc"

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

    val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
    val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    .............
                )
            }
        ) { contentPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding( all = 22.dp )
                ) {

                    .............

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Dropdown()
                        Dropdown()
                    }

                    ............
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of different methods to try and force/calculate the width and pass this to the component but it never makes to equal width fields!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `fillMaxWidth` you should use `weight` and it should work fine, and for using weight you can change the method like

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.Dropdown() {
}
```

or you can create the modifier in root method and you can pass that to the dropdown.

Use the below code for example,

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RowScope.Dropdown() {
    val ctx = LocalContext.current

    var coffeeDrinks = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three")

    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var selectedText by remember {
        mutableStateOf(coffeeDrinks[0])
    }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = expanded,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(all = 8.dp),
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }) {

        TextField(value = selectedText,
            onValueChange = {},
            readOnly = true,
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .menuAnchor()
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )

        ExposedDropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
            coffeeDrinks.forEach { item ->
                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = item) }, onClick = {
                    selectedText = item
                    expanded = false
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too easy, thank you Muthukrishnan, worked like a charm